# Change the text in a TextBox on button click in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have this easy little form in my JavaFX application.
I want to use a button to change `firstNameText` and `firstNameText`.

I'm not capable, I'm a newbie.  I tried the code below, where is my mistake?

```
def lastNameLabel = Label { text: "Last Name" };
def firstNameLabel = Label { text: "First Name" };
var lastNameText = TextBox { text: "Last Name" };
var firstNameText = TextBox { text: "First Name" };

def cancelButton = Button { 
    text: "Cancel" 
    action: function() {
        lastNameText = TextBox { text: "ciao" };
        firstNameText = TextBox { text: "ciao" };

    }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are creating 2 new textboxes instead of updating your 2 existing ones.

try

```
action: function() {
    lastNameText.text = "ciao";
    firstNameText.text = "ciao";
}
```